# How to make inline Completion stable after clicking the command uri of the vscode decoration's hover message

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created the vscode decorations with the following code:

```js
// editor: vscode.TextEditor
editor.setDecorations(decorationType, [{
    range,
    hoverMessage: new MarkdownString([show]($(Uri.parse('command:command.show'))))
}])
```

the command.show was registered to trigger a inline completion:

```js
vscode.commands.registerCommand('command.show', () => {
    commands.executeCommand('editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger');
})
```

the inline completion was registered and can be manually triggered.

[image]

However, the inline completion appears and disappears immediately after clicking the command Uri.

I tried setting `editor.selections` or `editor.revealRange` or executing `cursorMove`, but it didn't work.
Seems it occurs because the cursor is focused on the command Uri of the hover message.

I want to know how to focus the cursor on the editor instead of the hover message, or how to hide the hover message after clicking it.

Comment: execute command `editor.action.showHover` before `editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger` works!

Comment: you can write up an answer post :) see also [answer]